# Excel cell value depends from an other

Tags: excel, if-statement, ternary-operator

I hope that you can help me to solve this Excel problem.

I have 3 columns A, B, C

If the value of **B is equal to 0 then** I would like to **change the value of C to 0**

Any idea how I can achieve this?
Thank you in advance.

[Excel screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t703S.png)

Comment: And what if B is not equal to 0?

Comment: Check what IF statement does.

Comment: I just updated my post and upload a screenshot. So let me explain the whole story. I need to update the stock in Magento comerce but I don't want to do it manually. I need a CSV file with the SKU, Quantity and availability only.

The value of the availability cell has two options. 1 = In Stock. 0 = Out of stock. 

Somehow I have managed to change the quantity (column B) to 0 if it is less then 0. 

If I fill up the availability (column C) with 1 than I just need to change the  1 to 0 if B=0. 

I just don't know how :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

=IF(B1=0,0,"")
that's based on what you asked for.

Comment: I have tried this one but doesn't work: 
=IF(B3=0,"0","1")